# how to create a gloabal variable in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to develop a shopping cart where I have list of products , when user clicks on each product details will be displayed ,I want to add each product to global map or something when user clicks the add to cart button ,how can I achieve this?

for better understanding here is my link to plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/oo05d6H6AxuJGXBAUQvr?p=preview

This is my details page where I want to provide user with add to cart option:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <p>ItemName: {{itemName}}</p>
<p> ItemPrice: {{itemPrice|currency}}</p>
 <p>ItemRating:{{itemRating}}</p>
<img src="{{itemImage}}">
<p><input type = "submit" value = "Add to Cart" ng-click = "addProduct()"></p>
```

Comment: Use a service. AngularJS services are singletons. Global variables are evil.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/3aEJfg4FZJ5JsSAN85ni?p=preview) version.

There is a`cartService` defined here and injected in your `ItemCtrl`. All items are stored in a `cart` array inside the `cartService`.

Be aware that this works until you refresh the page. If you want to persist this `cart` variable so that it doesn't get erased during page refresh, you should look into `localStorage` or `$cookies`.

Comment: thank you,how do I display the items in the cart and also when I run the code the image is not getting displayed

Comment: Sorry for the image, i have edited the Plunker link to show the image as well. For showing cart items, you can create a new template called `cartDetails.html` and a controller for it. In your new controller, inject the `cartService` and create a variable to get cart items, for example `var carItems = cartService.getCart();`. Next, in your `cartDetails.html` you can display your cart items with `ng-repeat`.

Comment: hi, I have tried doing your way ,can u say where I'm going wrong in this code -https://plnkr.co/edit/oo05d6H6AxuJGXBAUQvr?p=preview

Comment: I have added `Total` to your cart details page in this one - https://plnkr.co/edit/cVArpCYCwJLbFCmUE6Y4?p=preview . Other than that, I'm not sure what else you want to do or what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your case a simple place to store the cart in the main controller, as it is accessible from the child controllers of the nested views. So here is how the `addProduct()` function could be implemented:

```
app.controller('mobileController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ...  

  $scope.cart = [];

  $scope.addProduct = function(item) {
    $scope.cart.push(item);
  }
});
```

and so the function could be called from the product details controller, provided you allow access to the viewed `item` in it:

```
<input type= "submit" value="Add to Cart" ng-click="addProduct(item)">
```

Since then you can display your updated cart in your main controller view (or in a child view of it, as it remains accessible):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in cart track by item.name">
  <li>{{item.name}}</li>
</div>
```

Should you want to add the same item multiple times, you'll have to display orders (or product serial numbers) instead of products.

Find the forked plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/7wz7VdyXMxcvjN9hkK6o?p=preview).

P.S.: Another option would be to store the cart in an Angular service, which would be injected in any controller that needs it.

P.P.S.: I kept on using the `$scope` as you did, but you should update your code to the latest Angular usages, such as using the `controllerAs` syntax and using controllers classes that can refer `this` (and a controller's name prefix in the templates) instead.